# Issue: Creating a drop down menu in Shiny R - not all objects are displayed

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have about 8000ish elements under 'gene_count', but only a few gets displayed when I create a dropdown menu using the command,

```
fluidRow(
             column(12,
                    br(),
                    selectInput("gene_search", label = h3("Gene of interest: "),
    choices = names(gene_count))
           )
           )
```

What could be the problem? Pl take a look at the screenshots below!

Thanks!

[Data stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drDZK.png)

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpVNs.png)

Comment: It appears that there is a size limit of 1000 https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/412

Comment: Is there a different approach to create a drop down menu with ~8K items to list?

Comment: Try set `selectize=F`

Comment: No luck with that as well.